# SVG renders incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I am working with SVG the first time and came across this problem:

I am using some SVGs for icons and everything works fine - except for one icon that renders incorrectly in Firefox on Windows. Firefox on OS X however renders it just fine.

Here is an anonymized version of the header I am placing SVG icons in:

http://files.uiux.de/140618_header/

That problem persists regardless if I use the Sprite utilized in the above example or if I use separate files for each icon.

Here are two screenshots of the render-issue I am experiencing. The problem is that little 'dent' on the lower end of that earphone:

[image]

We've saved those SVGs in Illustrator and used SVG 1.1 as export-setting.

Can someone point out what the problem seems to be here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that error in the sample header when I look at it with my version of FF (30).

It looks to me as if the artifact/'dent' you are seeing is caused by the left-most column of pixels of the envelope icon next to the phone in the sprite sheet.  You can tell if you zoom up the image.

What I do, to make sure things like this don't happen, is to not put icons hard up next to each other in the spritesheet.  Leave a few pixels gap between them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a version of that code locally that does not utilize a spritesheet and I still get that artifact on the phone icon in Windows 7 on the latest stable Firefox.

On OS X everything seems to render just fine.

Comment: That's weird then because I'm on Win7 also, and the SVG and the sample header render fine for me.

Comment: That is weird indeed. So far every machine running Win 7 I tested this with (including Browserstack) had this issue.